# Finding the general solution of the differential equation? y'+y=x

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Really want help to solve this questions.

Finding the general solution of the differential equation

$y'+y = x$ , $y(0) = 1$ , $x ∈ [0, 1]$, $n=5$ subintervals.

Comment: You might want to be more clear if you are looking for a numerical solution. Euler's method? Something else? Also, what have you tried? To find the general solution, you can use several approaches, but integrating factor works just fine.

Comment: I am looking for a numerical solution Euler's method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will map it out and you fill in the missing details.

Given:

$$\tag 1 \dfrac{dy}{dx}=x-y, y(0) = 1, h = \dfrac{b-a}{n} = \dfrac{1-0}{5} = 0.2$$

For $(1)$, using Euler's Method we have:

- $y_0 = 1$
- $y_{i+1} = y_i + hf(x_i,y_i) = y_i + 0.2(x_i - y_i)$
- $x_{i+1} = x_0 + i h = x_0 + .2 i$

Thus, the iterates are:

- $x_0 = 0, y_0 = 1$
- $y_1= y_0 + 0.2(x_0 - y_0) = 1 + 0.2(0 - 1) = 0.8$
- $x_1 = .2, y_1 = 0.8$
- $y_2= y_1 + 0.2(x_1 - y_1) = 0.68$
- You continue
- $\ldots$
- $y_5 = 0.6554$

You can compare the error from the Euler method to the exact result:

$$y(x) =  2 e^{-x} + x - 1$$

Comment: Very nice. But what is step bu step to find general solution? I want to learn how you get $y(x)=2e−x+x−1$

Comment: @Alex: Well, you can use an Integrating Factor or Laplace transform and several other approaches.